# I'm looking for a project management / to-do / GTD program

Tags: project-management, cross-platform

I am looking for a  project management / to-do / GTD whatever you want to call it software. I have looked/tried a large number but so far none fit

Requirements

- work across Windows Chrome OS/Browser and Android
- Task need to be able to me marked as dependent on another and then not show up if they are still waiting on another task to complete 1st
- Daily agenda showing what has to be done today and what can be done
- Templates for Projects and tasks
- Tasks to be able to be nested under multiple contexts
- Some simple scripting e.g when task A completes create task b and c from templates

Original messages before it was sugest i edit

Hi there

I'm looking for a project management / to-do / GTD whatever you want to call it software.
To help me keep track and prioritise my different projects. as well as my day to day tasks

The Projects that i am working have Parts that are published daily.
But the work to get them ready Is split into a number of stages and I work on getting a number of parts through each stage in batches.

Also there is the consideration that some stages I need to be at my main PC and it needs to be quite,  some i need to be at my PC but it doesn't matter about quiet,  some parts I can do on my laptop while hotelling on somebody else's computer  and some stages I can even do on my phone.
So ideally i would like to be able to use this software wherever i am,  so that if i find myself somewhere with some time on my hands i can see what need to be done and what i can do

I have tried a number of systems from something as low tech as a wall chart  that I ticked things off as I went along( but this has been the primary Downside of  me not being able to see this when I wasn't there)

I have tried creating a number of custom google sheet,  that was basically the wall chart but that  separate sheet was able to collect the information into one place  and colour code Things I Could See roughly what was going on.
 this evening work for a while but it was often buggy  So I couldn't trust the central sheet with actually displaying the correct information,  and I couldn't find a good system but it to inform me when something needed doing,  the  closest I got was adding widgets to every desktop I was a neer displaying the Google sheet and i could not use this for any other tasks i had

I have tried a number of dedicated  project management / GTD  And so far I can't seem to get a working system using them
(quick list of the ones i can remeber trying  Asana, Toodledo, Remember The Milk, Astrid, Todo, Orchestra, Evernote, Doit.im)
I'm not going to rule out these programs as they of updated or I might have just been missing something, although I did post on forums and message the developers

The closest I think I got was using Toodledo  where to create  Hundreds and hundreds of tasks at once but this just put in the system and made it unusable. It would be showing tasks which I knew I couldn't do because I haven't done the prerequisite tasks

In my head there are two ways I think something like this could work
1  I would need to be able to set tasks as dependent upon other tasks don't show up unless the prerequisites I met, 
2  have tasks automatically create a new task when the completed so for e.g. tick off that have i have produced Part 5 and the system makes a new task to produces Part 6 and a task to render part 5

almost forgot to say what OSsi use, Main desktop(windows 10), Secondary desktops(ubuntu) my laptop(chrome), and on my phone(android)

Thanks for your time any suggestions would be awesome

Regards 
Nick Tune

Comment: PS: Also click on the `project-management` tag to check [other related questions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management) – you might already find your answer there. The "related" section of this page holds some good candidates as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, just working on a requirements built points to edit in, i did look though other related questions  and i could not find any thing to fit

Answer (score -1):

Won't meet all of your specifications but might be worth to try:

- Trello: https://trello.com/
- Redmine: http://www.redmine.org/

Also see following question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130466/trac-vs-redmine-vs-jira-vs-fogbugz-for-one-man-shop

Comment: Thanks for the Answer,i have checked out Trello i don't believe it allows dependent tasks only sub tasks. not had chance to check out redmine yet as i have not been able to get to my main PC just my chrome book and i dont think i can install it on hear

Comment: I did not try it but there is a Trello extension for dependencies: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trello-card-dependencies/ddhnhdoghhfoeceiohphmjkcemlkkock    Also see   http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21444/how-do-you-handle-dependencies-between-cards-with-trello

Comment: For easier installation of Redmine see: https://bitnami.com/stack/redmine  Redmine features: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Features